# MS Project 2007 Saving Files as Project 2010-2013

Tags: ms-project

I have a user who has two versions of MS Project on their computer; Project 2007 and 2013. When they create a schedule in 2007 and save it, the saved file is listed as MS Project version 14 which I believe is MS Project 2010-2013.

I am attempting to check the version of the file by opening the schedule in Notepad and looking for the 'MSProject.MPP[version]' text.

To try and test I had the user save a blank project file in Project 2007, compared the blank 2007 project, the completed 2007 schedule, and a blank 2013 project that I created. When opened in Notepad, all three appear to be MSProject.MPP14 files.

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that an internal tool was opening the project file in the background with the default version of project. Since the user has both 2007 and 2013 installed and 2013 is the default version, when a certain function was run the project file created in 2007 was opened in 2013 which added the 2013 flags to the file.